# Why is my code not working when the targeted element is initially hidden?

Tags: jquery, traversal

This is what we were asked to do and the code that follows is what I did after modifying the second task.
the problem is that it only works when I disable the hide function imposed on item-body. But the exercise says it should be hidden initially. Could you please give me a hint  on how to obtain the same effect with the item-body hidden?

2. This task illustrates the sliding effects that can be produced with jQuery. Create a div with the class my-item that contains two other div tags, the first with the class item-header and the second with the class item-body. The item-header div contains an `<h2>` tag with some text (e.g. Click Me). The item-body div also contains some text, but the div is initially hidden. If the user clicks on the `<h2>` headline, the div item-body should slide down and its contents become visible. After another click on the headline, the div should slide up and its contents become invisible.
3. Extend your code from the previous task in such a way that a deep copy of the first div with the class my-item can be appended to the body of the document by clicking on a button. Be sure to modify your event handler from the previous task so that it also works for the new elements.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>event 3</title>
    <script src="library/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
     /*3.Extend your code from the previous task in such a way that a deep copy of the first div with the class my-item can be appended to the body of the document by clicking on a button. Be sure to modify your event handler from the previous task so that it also works for the new elements.*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#copy').click(function() {
                $('.my-item:last').clone().appendTo('body');
            });
            /*$('.item-body').hide();*/
            $(document).on('click', 'h2', function() {
                if ($(this).parent().next().children().is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).parent().next().children().slideUp();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().next().children().slideDown();
                }
                /*$(this).parent().next().children().clone().appendTo('body').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});// i first select the parent of my element then i select the next parent and its children (the paragraph inside item-body)*/
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='my-item'>
        <div class='item-header'>
            <h2>Jesus is the only Hope</h2>
        </div><!--closing tag for for div item-header-->

        <div class='item-body'>
            <p>je leve les yeux vers les monts que jaime dou peut me venir ici le secours. Le secours me vient de lEternel meme</p>
        </div><!--closing tag for the div item-body-->

    </div><!-- This is the closing tag of div my_item-->
    <button id='copy'>copy</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your test for visible/traversal:

```
$(this).parent().next().children().is(':visible')
```

matches the 2nd `p`

but you're not hiding the `p`, you're hiding the `div.item-body`

best bet is to change the slidedown to match the `div` rather than the `p`:

```
$('.item-body').hide();
$(document).on('click', 'h2', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).parent().next().slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

---

The clue is in the question: *the div item-body should slide down*

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  I spent hours thinking about it but I could not figure out what was wrong.

Comment: so sorry I did not accept your answer I only learnt how to do it today. Thanks a million times for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none`, but in the right element, then check if this element is visible.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>event 3</title>
  <script src="library/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  /*3.Extend your code from the previous task in such a way that a deep copy of the first div with the class my-item can be appended to the body of the document by clicking on a button. Be sure to modify your event handler from the previous task so that it also works for the new elements.*/

  $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#copy').click(function(){

            $('.my-item:last').clone().appendTo('body');

            });
        

            /*$('.item-body').hide();*/

             $(document).on( 'click','h2', function() {



               if($(this).parent().next().is(':visible')){

             $(this).parent().next().slideUp();

             }

             else{ 

             $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

             }

                /*$(this).parent().next().children().clone().appendTo('body').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});// i first select the parent of my element then i select the next parent and its children (the paragraph inside item-body)*/ 
            

                });






  });

  

  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <div class = 'my-item'>
    <div class = 'item-header'>
                 <h2>Jesus is the only Hope</h2>
    </div><!--closing tag for for div item-header-->

    <div class = 'item-body' style='display: none'>
                  <p>je leve les yeux vers les monts que jaime dou peut me venir ici le secours. Le secours me vient de lEternel meme</p>
    </div><!--closing tag for the div item-body-->

     </div><!-- This is the closing tag of div my_item-->
     <button id ='copy'>copy</button>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: so sorry I did not accept your answer I only learnt how to do it today. Thanks a million times for your help.